# DbContext gets disposed in ActionFilterAttribute, not reloaded on subsequent requests

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject

I'm trying to inject a UOW container into a WebApi 2 actionfilter attribute

```
 public class VerifyApiToken : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    [Inject]
    public IUOW Uow { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
       //get and save data to any repository in the uow container
       base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
    }
```

The UOW container gets injected like its supposed to and on the first request everything works fine. On subsequent request EF throws an exception saying that the DbContext has been disposed.

All the dependancies are bound in request scope, so its normal that the underlying dbcontext gets disposed. When using constructor injection in WebApi controllers everything works, resources are recreated on each request, why are they not recreated when trying to use Property injection in ActionFilterAttributes and how could this be resolved?

The IFilterProvider I'm using:

```
 public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(HttpConfiguration configuration, HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        IEnumerable<FilterInfo> controllerFilters = actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetFilters().Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, FilterScope.Controller));
        IEnumerable<FilterInfo> actionFilters = actionDescriptor.GetFilters().Select(instance => new FilterInfo(instance, FilterScope.Action));
        IEnumerable<FilterInfo> filters = controllerFilters.Concat(actionFilters);

        foreach (FilterInfo filter in filters)
        {
            _kernel.Inject(filter.Instance);
        }
        return filters;
    }
```

The "Inject" method description says "Injects the specified instance, without managing its lifecycle". So I take it that my VerifyApiToken attribute is injected once per App lifecycle (basically Application_Start) and thus on the following requests the same instance is used (with a disposed DbContext of course). 
Is it even possible to configure Ninject to use a new IUOW container for each request  in ActionFilterAttributes?

Answer (score 5):

Filters are cached and reused by the WebApi Framework. You should thus not inject any dependency in request scope; use a factory instead.

For more information see the [documentation](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Web.WebApi/wiki/Filters-and-Scopes)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow qujck's hint and instead inject a Func to the actionfilter.

It is required the following binding:

```
kernel.Bind<Func<IUOW>>().ToMethod(m => () => m.Kernel.Get<IUOW>());
```

Comment: This is a quick and easy way to create your factory